# data doesn't appear in my combobox at first time when select value from listbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have WPF listbox which contains employees names as displayed data ,combobox for countries and combobox for cities  ,when I select data from this list I want to show employee 's country & city at this two comboboxes like that

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--get employee name and add it to list-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmpFullNameTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmpFullName}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" 
                   FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="66*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="204*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="71*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="132*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="190*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Emp Country-->
    <TextBlock Name="blkEmpContries" Text=" الـبــلــد" Height="20" Margin="12,12,15,34" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="cmbContries" Height="20" Margin="0,12,18,34" 
              SelectionChanged="cmbContries_SelectionChanged" />
    <!-- Emp Country-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="blkEmpCities" Text=" الـمـحـافـظـة" Height="20" Margin="12,9,0,175" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="cmbEmpCities" Height="20" Margin="6,9,18,175" />

    <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,13,12,16" Name="lstEmployees" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}"  Background="Salmon"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmpFullNameTemplate}" Foreground="Black"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     BorderBrush="#FFAD7F30" SelectionChanged="lstEmployees_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid>

Int32 cntryID, crntEmpId, cityId;

    string ConStr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MenofiaHospital;User ID=mohamed;Password=ewies";

    #region get countries info
    // this is "" Stored Procedure
    // SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM dbo.CountriesTbl

    private void contriList()
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        // get all countries data      
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "SelAllCoubtries";
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dap.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        SqlCon.Close();
        bindContries(ds);
    }

    private void bindContries(DataSet dsGovs)
    {
        List<ContrisClass> cntrisList = new List<ContrisClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dsGovs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cntrisList.Add(new ContrisClass
                            (Convert.ToInt32(dsGovs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryID"]),
                            dsGovs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryName"].ToString()));
        }
        dsGovs = null;
        cmbContries.ItemsSource = cntrisList;
        cmbContries.DisplayMemberPath = "CountryName";
        cmbContries.SelectedValuePath = "CountryID";
    }
    #endregion

    #region get cities name according to selected country ID
    // This is "SelAllCities" StoredProcedure
    // select CityID,CityName from CitiesTbl where CountryID = @CountryID order by CityName

    private void citiesList(int CountryID)
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        // twons menu           
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "SelAllCities";
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlParameter ParCities = new SqlParameter();
        ParCities.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        ParCities.ParameterName = "@CountryID";
        ParCities.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        ParCities.Value = CountryID;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParCities);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dap.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        SqlCon.Close();
        bindTowns(ds);
    }

    private void bindTowns(DataSet dsTowns)
    {
        List<CityClass> townList = new List<CityClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dsTowns.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            townList.Add(new CityClass
                         (Convert.ToInt32(dsTowns.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CityID"]),
                         dsTowns.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CityName"].ToString()));
        }
        dsTowns = null;
        cmbEmpCities.ItemsSource = townList;
        cmbEmpCities.DisplayMemberPath = "CityName";
        cmbEmpCities.SelectedValuePath = "CityID";
    }

    private void cmbContries_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        cntryID = Convert.ToInt32(this.cmbContries.SelectedValue);
        citiesList(cntryID);
    }
    #endregion

    #region get all employees 

    // this is "SelEmpsInfo" StoredProcedure from SQL Server
    // SELECT EmpID, EmpFullName FROM dbo.EmployeesTble 

    private void bindEmployeesInfo()
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        // guests menu           
        SqlCommand SqlCmdAllEmpsInfo = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmdAllEmpsInfo.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmdAllEmpsInfo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmdAllEmpsInfo.CommandText = "SelEmpsInfo";
        SqlCon.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dap1.SelectCommand = SqlCmdAllEmpsInfo;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        dap1.Fill(ds1, "EmployeesTble");
        SqlCon.Close();
        lstEmployees.DataContext = ds1;
    }
    #endregion



    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        contriList();
        bindEmployeesInfo();
    }

    #region get Employee info according to selected value from listbox and bind it to comboboxes
    // this is "SelAllEmpInfo" StoredProcedure

    // SELECT dbo.EmployeesTble.CityID, dbo.CitiesTbl.CityName, dbo.CitiesTbl.CountryID, 
    // dbo.CountriesTbl.CountryName FROM  dbo.CitiesTbl INNER JOIN dbo.CountriesTbl ON 
    // dbo.CitiesTbl.CountryID = dbo.CountriesTbl.CountryID INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeesTble 
    // ON dbo.CitiesTbl.CityID = dbo.EmployeesTble.CityID where EmployeesTble.EmpID = @EmpID

    public ArrayList SelAllEmpInfo(Int32 EmpId)
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "SelAllEmpInfo";
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlParameter ParEmpId = new SqlParameter();
        ParEmpId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        ParEmpId.ParameterName = "@EmpID";
        ParEmpId.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt;
        ParEmpId.Value = EmpId;
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParEmpId);

        SqlDataReader Dr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList empList = new ArrayList();
        if (Dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (Dr.Read())
            {
                empList.Add(Dr[0].ToString());
                empList.Add(Dr[1].ToString());
                empList.Add(Dr[2].ToString());
                empList.Add(Dr[3].ToString());
            }
        }
        SqlCon.Close();
        return empList;
    }

    private void lstEmployees_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRowView drv = lstEmployees.SelectedValue as DataRowView;

            crntEmpId = Convert.ToInt32(drv["EmpID"]);

            ArrayList empList = SelAllEmpInfo(crntEmpId);

            cmbEmpCities.DisplayMemberPath = empList[1].ToString();
            cmbEmpCities.Text = empList[1].ToString();
            cmbEmpCities.SelectedValuePath = empList[0].ToString();
            cityId = Convert.ToInt32(empList[0]);

            cmbContries.DisplayMemberPath = empList[3].ToString();
            cmbContries.Text = empList[3].ToString();
            cmbContries.SelectedValuePath = empList[2].ToString();
            contriList();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    #endregion
}


class ContrisClass
{
    private int _ContryID = -1;
    private string _ContryName = "";

    public ContrisClass(int contryID, string contryName)
    {
        this._ContryID = contryID;
        this._ContryName = contryName;
    }

    public int CountryID
    {
        get { return _ContryID; }
        set { _ContryID = value; }
    }

    public string CountryName
    {
        get { return _ContryName; }
        set { _ContryName = value; }
    }
}

class CityClass
{
    private int _CityID = -1;
    private string _CityName = "";

    public CityClass(int cityID, string CityName)
    {
        this._CityID = cityID;
        this._CityName = CityName;
    }
    public int CityID
    {
        get { return _CityID; }
        set { _CityID = value; }
    }
    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _CityName; }
        set { _CityName = value; }
    }
}
```

my problem is when I select data from list box "employee name" nothing appear in both comboboxes , but in debug mode I see data retrieved from array list and binding to comboboxes.

any help please, thanks.

Comment: Till now no answer, please I need urgent help.

Answer (score 0):

From `bindContries` method remove `cmbContries.SelectedValuePath = "CountryID";`. Also from `bindTowns` method remove `cmbEmpCities.SelectedValuePath = "CityID";`

Finally, change `lstEmployees_SelectionChanged` method content to:

```
private void lstEmployees_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataRowView drv = lstEmployees.SelectedValue as DataRowView;

        crntEmpId = Convert.ToInt32(drv["EmpID"]);

        ArrayList empList = SelAllEmpInfo(crntEmpId);

        int countryID = empList[your index to country ID];
        var countries = (cmbContries.ItemsSource as List<ContrisClass>);
        int countryToSelect = countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CountryID == countryID);

        cmbContries.SelectedValue = countryToSelect;

        int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(empList[0]);
        var cities = (cmbEmpCities.ItemsSource as List<CityClass>);
        var cityToSelect = cities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CityID == cityId);

        cmbEmpCities.SelectedValue = cityToSelect;

    }
    catch { }
}
```